# How to preserve pdf file sizes when working on photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I modified some details on a pdf in photoshop but after saving it again as a pdf , photoshop changes the file size somehow, even though the editing was done at only a small portion inside the page.Original file size was 839 x 595 but once saved again, it becomes 814 × 546 points.  What can I do so that photoshop preserves the file size ? Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  For me, a PDF opens the same size in Photoshop, and saves the same size.  There may be other issues here that are file specific, but without access to the files it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Once you opened the PDF in Photoshop you rasterized everything. That is to say, you converted all the information into a pixelated version of itself. Rather than keeping all the Postscript, Font and Vector information. This expands the file size greatly.

If you need to do an edit to an existing PDF try using the Edit features in Adobe Acrobat.

To edit text and photos in Acrobat: EDIT > Edit Text & Images

[image: EDIT > Edit Text & Images]

Then use the edit tools to the right.

[image: Edit tools]

You may run into font issues if you do not have the original fonts, and some things may jump around on the pages. There are many tools out there to help you in editing PDF's (See PitStop Pro). So be sure to review all pages after editing.

Comment: The problem is that I need to edit some page numbers and colors etc of an existing product catalogue so photoshop is the only way.

Comment: You can edit most of that stuff  in Acrobat. However, when I edit things like that I usually place the catalogue pages into a new document in InDesign. Then I can edit the pdf pages as I need to, and make edits where I can, then re-make a new pdf. Never underestimate the power of placing a white box over something!! Unless you can get the original files, keeping the pdf in it's native form is best.

Comment: That is actually what I ended up trying now in the meantime in InDesign . Thanks a lot!!!!